# Call a function taking a stack object as argument with heap based data

Tags: c++, assembly, parameter-passing, heap-memory, inline-assembly

I have a complex problem to be solve, as I am stuck and found no way at all to solve this.
Here's a code

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int x;    
    float y;
    char c;
};

void foo(MyStruct a_myStruct);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])    
{
    void *pMyStruct = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
    int* pInt = (int*)pMyStruct;

    *pInt = 10;    
    pInt++;

    float *pFloat = (float*)pInt;    
    *pFloat = 2.545;   
    pFloat++;

    char *pChar = (char*)pFloat;
    *pChar = 'c';

    _asm
    {
        pMyStruct
        call foo
    }

    return 0;
}

void foo(MyStruct a_myStruct)
{
}
```

Here you can see that `foo` is operating on an object on the stack and is expecting the stack object to be mapped when `foo` gets called. But unfortunately the `MyStruct` type is not known at compile time so I have to create blocks of memory and then at runtime data is filled within that block which is then passed when `foo` gets called with asm as show above.

Now how can I convert a heap void pointer into stack type object. Somehow if I get the address of the `a_myStruct` argument of `foo`, I can point with `void*` to that location but again I can't dereference `void*` so that it gets converted into an object of `MyStruct` type.

Any other way around to solve the problem? As in C++ we can determine type at runtime as well.

---

I have a problem to call functions at run time in C++ which might have signature with full of user defined types that are not known at compile time.But details of those types are available to me(As I deciphered details of certain type from type library or from DIA SDK). But the main problem is now i want to call these functions at runtime. At compile time I just have address of function and details of user defined type of which object or pointer is participating as argument of that function signature. Now If i want to call that function at run time, i need to populate that type at runtime first by creating temporary block on heap and filling that block with the data .I have all details of that type.

Now problem is i don't know that function taking argument as pointer of that type of which I have details available or that argument is exactly the stack object of that type. If i have pointer to that type no problem, but if object there i have big problem to call that function at runtime.

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to do here?  This code makes absolutely no sense, whatsoever.  Perhaps you should take a step backwards and explain the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Attempting to cast a struct to pointers to the types that it has for member variables implies that you don't have a clue how structs work. I'm with James on this one. This code makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I suspect the OP is trying to modify the member of the struct of the type to which its being cast in each case. The why still puzzles me completely.

Comment: @Jonathan : mistake of type casting has been corrected.

Comment: My guess is he's trying to crack someone's copy protection.

Comment: @Ashelly : I have made the comment as answer 
Can you please see my comments at the end..?  I briefly describe what's the problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you think you need to populate your struct the way you are showing, but regardless, you are doing it wrong.

It would need to be more like:

```
int* pInt = (int*)pMyStruct;   
*pInt++ = 10;   
 float *pFloat = (float*)pInt;   
 *pFloat++ = 2.545;   
 char *pChar = (char*)pFloat;   
 *pChar = 'c';
```

Which is completely platform dependent, and probably won't work right either.

Assuming you get myStruct populated, One simple solution to calling `foo` would be to change it to this:to

```
void foo(MyStruct* pMyStruct);
```

If that's not possible, you need to copy it to the stack.    Something like

```
 char rawBytes[sizeof(MyStruct)];
 memcpy(&rawBytes,MyStruct,sizeof(MyStruct));
 foo(*(MyStruct*)rawBytes)`
```

might work.  Or not, since you don't know MyStruct at compile time, the compiler can't generate the stack manipulation code.

I'm assuming you do know at runtime how big MyStruct is.  So it's got to be more like this:

```
 _asm{ 
    //pseudo-assembly
    cx = numBytesInMyStruct
    bx = pointerToYourFakeMyStruct
    loop cx
     push *bx++
    call foo
 }
```

Comment: I think copying the data on to stack might help but unfortunately it's not getting work here. It fails to copy properly. More over here MyStruct is a complete type, which is not known at compile time. So a char array won't work here.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that even with the additional information you provided, I don't fully understand your question. But **let me say something general about the stack and the heap and C++:**

**How an argument gets passed to the function is an implementation detail** of a particular C++ compiler, ie. this can vary from one C++ compiler to the next. The method by which arguments are passed into functions is called a ***calling convention***. Some compilers use neither the stack nor the heap for argument passing; instead, they use CPU registers if possible. (Watcom's C++ compiler is/was a prominent example of a compiler that favours registers to pass arguments to a function.)

This means that any C++ compiler may create binaries that are not ***binary-compatible*** to another C++ compiler. (The C++ language standard does not prescribe a binary standard for compiled output, therefore different compilers may produce binary-incompatible output; but any C++ compiler is guaranteed to be binary-compatible at least to itself.) Thus, if you want to use a library, you have three options:

- choose a binary that matches your particular C++ compiler and linker;
- compile the library sources yourself, using your compiler; or
- choose a library binary that adheres to a certain binary standard (such as the DLL library format or Microsoft's COM standard) which is also supported by your C++ compiler and linker.

In conclusion, **your question about stack object vs. heap object does not make sense**. There is no such thing as a "stack object" in C++. You have no explicit control how an argument is passed to a function, because that is something that the C++ compiler will decide itself how to do -- and while there seem to exist keywords and special syntax to control this behaviour (namely references, pointers, as well as the `auto` and `register` keywords), they *generally* won't give you any guarantee that a parameter will be passed in a specific way. If you know one *particular* compiler well, then you might be able to deduce how parameter passing works with this compiler... but *generally*, you cannot — and should not have to — know about this mechanism.

**P.S.:** I forgot to mention that the term "stack object" is not just meaningless in terms of parameter passing. Even more generally, there simply isn't any way to tell the compiler to allocate an object on the stack. While local variables usually *will* be allocated on the stack, there is no guarantee whatsoever for this. I suppose that is why you chose to escape into assembly language. You could then explicitly `push` and `pop` values to/from the stack (as managed by the CPU).